# How do you make django form validation dynamic?

Tags: django, forms

I have a form that needs to have either a valid url or a valid file for uploading:

```
class ResourceUpload(ModelForm):
   ...        
   uploadedfile = forms.FileField('file')
   url_address = forms.URLField('url') 
   ...
```

How can I override the `FileField` and `URLField` validators so that Django only raises an error if both of the fields above are invalid but excepts one being invalid so long as the other is valid?

Answer (score 8):

my solution
pros: it keeps the asterisk for the really required field and default error messages

```
class Form(forms.ModelForm):
    field1 = SelectField
    field2 = ...
    field3 = ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if kwargs['data']:
            if kwargs['data'].get('field1') == '1':
                self.fields['field2'].required = True
                self.fields['field3'].required = False
            elif kwargs['data'].get('field1') == '2':
                self.fields['field2'].required = False
                self.fields['field3'].required = True
```

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to set them both as `required=False`, so the database backend doesn't need them both filled in, and then use [form cleaning](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other):

```
import forms

class ResourceUpload(ModelForm):
   ...        
   uploadedfile = forms.FileField(required = False, upload_to='put/files/here')
   url_address = forms.URLField(required = False) 
   ...

   def clean(self):
       cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
       uploadedfile = cleaned_data.get("uploadedfile ")
       url_address = cleaned_data.get("url_address ")

       if not uploadedfile and not url_address :
           raise forms.ValidationError("Provide a valid file or a valid URL.")
       
       return cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's my solution which really works... (tested)

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(YourForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    if self.data and self.data.get('field_name') != 'SOMETHING':
        self.fields.get('field_name2').required = True
```

This makes `field_name2` a required field if `field_name`'s input was not `'SOMETHING'`. 
Django rocks!

Comment: Django really rocks!

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this package [django-extra-field-validation](https://github.com/tj-django/django-extra-field-validation)

```
from django.db import models
from extra_validator import FieldValidationMixin


class MyModel(FieldValidationMixin, models.Model):
    uploadedfile = models.FileField(upload_to='upload/path', blank=True, default='')
    url_address = models.URLField(blank=True, default='') 
    
    REQUIRED_TOGGLE_FIELDS = ['uploadedfile', 'url_address']
```

This will validate that only one of the fields can be provided raising validation error if both are used.

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: You shouldn't be too quick to comment because I already added the usage.

Comment: Yeah, that was after the comment though. FGITW isn't a problem when the question was asked over 8 years ago; just add it in the first revision and you won't get comments and flags. I've retracted mine though