# Dynamically load Django Form from database

Tags: django, database, forms

I'm not even sure how to ask this correctly but here it goes. **Is there a way with [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) to load `Form object` from database.**

> Example

Let's say we have a basic contact form, that looks something like this:

```
from django import forms


class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    body = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.Textarea
    )
```

How would I allow users to add initial data or to change which fields are required. Or maybe even allow then to add a new field via some kind of interface.

Specifically, I have multiple uses in my app and want to allow then to customize `Contact Form`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I suspect this question is too broad for SO. You might want to look a third party libraries like [django-dynamic-forms](https://github.com/MarkusH/django-dynamic-forms).

Comment: this is really cool question!! I dont think this is possible yet in django.

Comment: You can use [initial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#initial) - and load these values form a "settings" model or form wherever needed.

Comment: @ohrstrom: you are right about that, i could probably use same technique for widget attributes.

Comment: You can change the attributes dynamically via the form's `__init__` - e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18363555/469111